# Is flagging duplicate topics in Documentation the appropriate action to take or is there another way to say a topic exists more than once?

Tags: support, documentation

In the Python documentation, there are two topics discussing the differences between Python 2 and Python 3:

- [First](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/809/python-3-vs-python-2#t=201607211256455670812)
- [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/742/writing-code-compatible-with-python-2-and-python-3#t=201607211257056140746)

I issued a flag on the second one and selected "unnecessary" as the reason. However, the text box that appeared wasn't what I was expecting (I was expecting something more akin to flagging a duplicate question, where I would be presented with the option to select the duplicate target). I added a note to the text box pointing out the original.

Is this the appropriate action to take when there are duplicates or did I miss an option to indicate a duplicate target?

Comment: Also the ability to flag duplicates **within** a topic would be helpful, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/809/python-3-vs-python-2/2999/the-next-method#t=201607211353110284346 and http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/809/python-3-vs-python-2/3064/next-function-and-next-method#t=201607211353110284346

Comment: I think duplication is going to be a big issue in documentation. After briefly browsing the [linq] tag I immediately found three examples covering the same feature.